# Handling bi-directional properties when serializing (if I need both)

Tags: json, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm

I have two Entities:

Organization with some packages:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Package", mappedBy="organization", cascade={"all"})
 **/
private $packages;
```

And the package which belongs to a organization:

```
/**
 *
 * @var string @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Organization", inversedBy="packages", cascade={"all"})
 *      @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="organization", referencedColumnName="id")
 *      })
 */
private $organization;
```

Now I have two use cases: I want to get to one organization with all packages in serialized form. But I also need to display the package (also serialized) with the information to which organization it belongs.

When I do simply serialize the results, lets say the organization (the packages are serialized the same way):

```
 // Serialize to json
    $serializer = new Serializer(array(
        new GetSetMethodNormalizer()
    ), array(
        'json' => new JsonEncoder()
    ));
    $json = $serializer->serialize($result, 'json');
    return $json;
```

I'm running into the problem that it will serialize the organization, and get all packages and in those packages it will get search for the organization (which has again the list with the packages and so on). So I'm running into a infinite loop.

Is there a best practice for doing stuff like that? Or do I have create two classes which don't have the properties like defined above and then wrap it to that classes?

I use the serializing method for all objects I want to get in JSON format.

Comment: Downvote without a reason. Thanks to that human being for waste his score points... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I solved my problem with the [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) look at the `MaxDepth()` property